# Do action after Push Notification arrives when screen is locked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Is it posible to do some action after Push Notification arrives when screen is locked and opened without click Push Notification? I have observed these methods but none is called:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler 

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

Comment: when your app is suspended/killed/inactive iOS handles the push notifications. none of these methods will be called until user interacts with notification. So answer is no u cant do any action if your app is suspended/killed on receiving APNS

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the regular push notification, so the answer is no.
You can use the silent notifications - this type of notification will not display any alert to the user but will inform your app about a new content available. Your app wakes up in the background each time such notification arrive.
There is an option with the VoIP push notifications in case of a VoIP application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to handle push notifications,

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler {

    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;

    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"data messages555 %@", userInfo);

    //here you will get user info. Push notificationd data

    NSLog(@"Data121 : %@",userInfo);
    completionHandler();

   // write code for handling push notifications
   // write code to handle action after clicking on the push notifications


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can perform actions on notification once it get arrived, By adding **"Notification Service Extension"** to your app. Also you need to add **"content-available = 1"** in your Payload. In your apps **Capabilities, enable "Remote Notifications" in "Background Modes"**.